# how to pass parameters to XQUERY in JBOSS FUSE ESB

Tags: apache-camel, xquery, fuseesb, jbossfuse

### XQUERY:

```
 declare namespace ns5 = "http://sample.com/schema/Order/v1/";
 declare namespace ns2 = "http://sample.com/schema/Order/v1/";
 declare variable $name as xs:string external;
 declare variable $details as element() external;
 let $Address := $details/ns5:ContactInfo
 return
     <ns5:GetDetailsResponse>

           <ns2:Name>$Address/ns2:name</ns2:Name>
           <ns2:ID Version="1.5">Order service</ns2:ID>

        <ns2:Reference>
           <ns2:ID>{$name}</ns2:ID>
        </ns2:Reference>           

   </ns5:GetDetailsResponse>
```

### Camel Route:

```
 <to uri="xquery:sampleXQUERY.xq"/>
```

Using XQUERY endpoint in camel route of FUSE ESB.

How can I pass the values to the variables $name, $details declared in this XQUERY??

I have tried using setHeader before this endpoint. But not able to pass values to XQUERY.

Please suggest solution!!

Comment: Pls do answer. Suggest

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/languages/xquery-language.html), you can pass values by setting `exchange.properties` or `exchange.in.headers`.

For example:

```java
from("direct:myRoute")
        .setProperty("someProperty", simple("some value"))
        .transform().xquery("/some/xquery");
```